# Random number changes each time I access the variable

Tags: java, random

I am trying to generate and then save a random number.

However every time I access the variable that contains the random String, it get's re-created i.e. the variable is then set to a new random String. I can't understand why accessing the variable is changing it.

I'm building some 'forgotten password' functionality.

The main class looks like this:

```
public class PasswordRecoverer{

@Id
public ObjectId id;
public String email;
public String key;
public Long expires;

public PasswordRecoverer create(String email){

    this.email = email;
    this.key = getKey();
    Calendar cal =  Calendar.getInstance();
    this.expires = cal.getTimeInMillis() + 3600000; // expires in 1hr

    return this;
}

// more code here ...

}
```

I am accessing (and printing) the `key` variable in my controller class, and I can see it changes each time.

Btw: `p.rint()` that I use below is just a `class.method()` shorthand for `System.out.println()`

public class App extends Controller{

public static void resetPassword(String email){

```
PasswordRecoverer pr = new PasswordRecoverer();
    p.rint(1, pr.key);
    if(new PasswordRecoverer().read(email)==null){
        p.rint(2, pr.key);
        pr = new PasswordRecoverer().create(email);
        p.rint(3,pr.key);
    }
    else{
        p.rint(4,pr.key);
        pr = new PasswordRecoverer().update(email);
        p.rint(5,pr.key);
    }
    p.rint(6, pr.key);
    pr.save();
    p.rint(7,pr.key);
    p.rint(pr.key);
    p.rint(8,pr.key);

render("App/forgot-pwd.html")
  }
}
```

Everytime I do `p.rint(x,pr.key)` ... `pr.key` has a different value. I would like it to be the same each time.

Comment: You're creating a new object most of the time. Why are you surprised to see a different value?

Comment: What is `x` in `p.rint(x, pr.key)`. Could you post the code?

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to diagnose the problem. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @shmosel its because whenever he calls print he creates new instance of PasswordRecover

Comment: @EduardoDennis Yes, I pointed that out.

Comment: Yep thanks, I'm refactoring it. That was totally stupid, but still getting some issues. Will double check - probably the same issue, but hidden elsewhere. Will update q soon. Thanks/

Comment: and p.rint is `public static void rint(String s1, Object s2){
        p.rint(s1 + " / " + s2);
    }`

Comment: and ... public static void rint(String s){
System.out.println(s);
    }

Comment: I see I wasn't making much sense earlier ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because each print you are instantiating a new `PasswordRecover`, which in turn gets a new key.

Possible Solution

It seems each new PasswordRecover class needs to have a unique key. but don't use the new constructor, rather use the create(email);

```
if(email!= null){
PasswordRecoverer pr = PasswordRecoverer.create(email);
    p.rint(1, pr.key);
    }
   else{
       // Logic for when you do not have email
    }
    p.rint(6, pr.key);
    pr.save();
    p.rint(7,pr.key);
    p.rint(pr.key);
    p.rint(8,pr.key);

pr.save();

render("App/forgot-pwd.html")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ... a related but probably stupid question. Would it make sense to have the PasswordRecoverer as a singleton, initially my design was like that. Or is that not a good idea?

Comment: @Ankur I think that would cause issues because of each PasswordRecover class has email, id, which has to be unique for different requests. I am not sure about your full application, but if they needs to be the same for everyone maybe you can just put in static final variable in password recover class, or singleton. But making the Password Recover class singleton seems like it would be problematic.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I've cleaned the code up a lot but still have a similar issue. Will follow your suggestion.

Comment: thanks this helped. I've ended up with something similar:

Comment: Which is: PasswordRecoverer pr = new PasswordRecoverer().read(email);
        if(pr==null){
            pr = new PasswordRecoverer();
        }

        String theKey = pr.getKey();
        pr.email = email;
        pr.key = theKey;
        pr.expires = pr.getExpires();
        pr.save();